# Dynamic LookupOrderRows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Using AMPScript, I want to pass from a URL Attribute lookup variables and use these variables in my LookupOrderRows function.

The challenge is that not all lookup variables have to be passed by the URL e.g I might lookup just 'office' or I could also lookup both 'office' and 'score.

I've tried several approaches of Concat the string etc - but can't see to make the lookup work.

Has anyone had any success performing similar?

```
IF not empty( Requestparameter("office") ) then 
Set @field1_name = "OFFICE"
Set @field1_value = Requestparameter("office") 
EndIf

IF not empty( Requestparameter("specialism") ) then 
Set @field2_name = "SPECIALISM"
Set @field2_value = Requestparameter("specialism") 
EndIf

IF not empty( Requestparameter("score") ) then 
Set @field3_name = "SCORE"
Set @field3_value = Requestparameter("score") 
EndIf


set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@LeadsDE,0,"[Engagement Activity Date] desc",@Field1_Name,@Field1_Value,@Field2_Name,@Field2_Value,@Field3_Name,@Field3_Value)
```

My current solution is a lot If then statements and combinations i.e. :

```
/* OFFICE ONLY*/
IF NOT EMPTY(@input_office) AND EMPTY(@input_organisation) AND EMPTY(@input_specialism)  AND EMPTY(@input_score) then
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@LeadsDE,0,"[Engagement Activity Date] desc","OFFICE",@input_office)
ENDIF

/* OFFICE + ORG*/
IF NOT EMPTY(@input_office) AND NOT EMPTY(@input_organisation) AND EMPTY(@input_specialism)  AND EMPTY(@input_score) then
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@LeadsDE,0,"[Engagement Activity Date] desc","OFFICE",@input_office,"ORGANISATION_NAME",@input_organisation)
ENDIF
/* OFFICE + ORG + SPECIALISM */
IF NOT EMPTY(@input_office) AND NOT EMPTY(@input_organisation) AND NOT EMPTY(@input_specialism)  AND EMPTY(@input_score) then
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@LeadsDE,0,"[Engagement Activity Date] desc","OFFICE",@input_office,"ORGANISATION_NAME",@input_organisation,"SPECIALISM",@input_specialism)
ENDIF
/* OFFICE + ORG + SCORE */
IF NOT EMPTY(@input_office) AND NOT EMPTY(@input_organisation) AND EMPTY(@input_specialism)  AND NOT EMPTY(@input_score) then
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@LeadsDE,0,"[Engagement Activity Date] desc","OFFICE",@input_office,"ORGANISATION_NAME",@input_organisation,"Engagement Score",@input_score)
ENDIF
/* OFFICE + ORG + SPECIALISM + SCORE  */
IF NOT EMPTY(@input_office) AND NOT EMPTY(@input_organisation) AND NOT EMPTY(@input_specialism)  AND EMPTY(@input_score) then
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@LeadsDE,0,"[Engagement Activity Date] desc","OFFICE",@input_office,"ORGANISATION_NAME",@input_organisation,"SPECIALISM",@input_specialism,"Engagement Score",@input_score)
ENDIF

IF NOT EMPTY(@input_office) AND EMPTY(@input_organisation) AND NOT EMPTY(@input_specialism)  AND EMPTY(@input_score) then
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@LeadsDE,0,"[Engagement Activity Date] desc","OFFICE",@input_office,"SPECIALISM",@input_specialism)
ENDIF

IF NOT EMPTY(@input_office) AND EMPTY(@input_organisation) AND NOT EMPTY(@input_specialism)  AND NOT EMPTY(@input_score) then
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@LeadsDE,0,"[Engagement Activity Date] desc","OFFICE",@input_office,"SPECIALISM",@input_specialism,"Engagement Score",@input_score)
ENDIF

IF NOT EMPTY(@input_office) AND EMPTY(@input_organisation) AND EMPTY(@input_specialism)  AND NOT EMPTY(@input_score) then
    set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@LeadsDE,0,"[Engagement Activity Date] desc","OFFICE",@input_office,"Engagement Score",@input_score)
ENDIF
```

Comment: First note, you are not using the `@` before your AMPscript variables when setting them in the conditions. I haven't checked the rest yet though so may not be the complete solution to your issue.

Comment: Hey Gortonington - apologies, the code was writtien whilst on a train - it does have @ 

I'm just trying to simplify the lookup logic - but so far have resorted to loads of it statements (second post)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'll be working with a variable combination of fields and want to build your lookup's where clause dynamically, you could try leveraging the [TreatAsContent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/treatascontent.htm) function.

I tested the following on my end and it appears to work:

```
%%[
/*
var @dataExt,
    @fieldSort,
    @officeName,
    etc...
*/ 

set @dataExt = 'some_de'
set @fieldSort = 'some_field DESC'


/* expected fields */
set @officeName = 'office'
set @officeVal = RequestParameter(@officeName)

set @specialismName = 'specialism'
set @specialismVal = RequestParameter(@specialismName)

set @scoreName = 'score'
set @scoreVal = RequestParameter(@scoreName)


/* use characters that won't appear in field names or values */
set @separator = '~'
set @delimiter = '`'

/* create name-value string based on expected fields */
set @nameValPairs = Concat(
  @officeName, @separator, @officeVal, @delimiter,
  @specialismName, @separator, @specialismVal, @delimiter,
  @scoreName, @separator, @scoreVal
)


/* create name-value collection */
set @fieldRowset = BuildRowsetFromString(@nameValPairs, @delimiter)


/* build where clause */
set @whereClause = ''

for @i = 1 to RowCount(@fieldRowset) do
  set @row = Row(@fieldRowset, @i)
  set @item = Field(@row, 1)
  set @fieldName = Substring(@item, 1, Subtract(IndexOf(@item, @separator), 1))
  set @fieldVal = Substring(@item, Add(IndexOf(@item, @separator), 1))

  if not Empty(@whereClause) and not Empty(@fieldVal) then
    set @whereClause = Concat(@whereClause, ',')
  endif

  if not Empty(@fieldVal) then
    set @whereClause = Concat(@whereClause, '"', @fieldName, '","', @fieldVal, '"')
  endif
next @i


if not Empty(@whereClause) then
]%%
%%=TreatAsContent(Concat("%", "%[set @rowset = LookupOrderedRows(@dataExt,0,@fieldSort,", @whereClause, ")]%", "%"))=%%
%%[
Output(Concat('Where Clause: (', @whereClause, ')<br>'))
Output(Concat('Row Count: ', RowCount(@rowset)))

else
  Output(Concat('Missing valid field name-value pairs'))
endif
]%%
```

Comment: Mark - you are a genius !! Thank very much for this answer - it was spot on and works a treat. Your solution has considerably reduced the amount of code in a very useful and expandable approach. Kudos to you my friend !

Answer (score 0):

I just tested a simplified version of your code and it works as expected:

```
%%[ Set @Field1_Name = 'NAME1'
set @Field2_Name = 'NAME2'
set @de = 'DENAME'
set @Field1_Value = 'VALUE1'
set @Field2_Value = 'VALUE2'


set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@de,0,"FIELDNAME desc",@Field1_Name,@Field1_Value,@Field2_Name,@Field2_Value)

]%%

%%=rowcount(@rows)=%%
```

This returns a value of 1 which is expected

To begin troubleshooting your issue I would print out your Variables to ensure they are the values you expect. If you aren't using a an content builder to test your ampscript, where you simply set a value where you would expect a requestparameter

I also don't see where you set a value for your VAR when the requestparameter is empty

You can also review using an [iif()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/iif.htm) statement to simplify your if statements

```
set @field1 = IIF(EMPTY(Requestparameter("office")),'office',Requestparameter("office"))=%%
```

Comment: Thanks EazyE - I don't think my question was clear enough - it's a difficult one to explain. 

What I ideally wanted to do is eliminate the need for doing lots of IF/THEN statements to set the LookupOrdered Rows.

Something like this : 

set @rows = LookupOrderedRows(@de,0,"FIELDNAME desc",IIF (NOT EMPTY(@Field1_Name), '@Field1_Name,@Field1_Value',''),IIF (NOT EMPTY(@Field2_Name), '@Field2_Name,@Field2_Value','') )


I've tried Concat, IIF etc and can't see to get it to work. 
My output string formats correct, but LookupRows doesnt accept LookupRows(@MyString)